# Defining role-based access to the Devise User model

Tags: devise, cancan, ruby-on-rails-3

Can anyone point me towards documentation on this?

I'm using Devise + CanCan in a Rails3 app, and setting up Ability.rb.

I want to restrict access to the edit/ delete User paths, depending on the user's role. Normally Ability.rb would be something like :

```
def initialize(user)        
    if user.role? :moderator
       can :manage, User
    end
end
```

But in the views I'm using the Devise registration paths for edit/ delete:

```
<% if can? :update, @user %>
     <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_registration_path(@user) %> | 
<% end %>
```

"can :manage, User" doesn't seem to apply to these paths, and they remain hidden irrespective of role.

If I use "can :manage, :all", then these paths can be accessed by the moderator user.

So, "User" clearly isn't the correct model to manage. I've tried "Devise" and "Registration", to no avail.

What value should I be using - "can :manage, ????" - and where can I find documentation to explain why?

Thank you for any pointers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problems you are facing, I faced them back in my last project.
This link will get you all your answers.

[Rails-authentication-with-devise-and-cancan-restful-resources-for-administrators](http://www.tonyamoyal.com/2010/09/29/rails-authentication-with-devise-and-cancan-part-2-restful-resources-for-administrators/)

Hope it helps.

Comment: @jatin thanks for the link to useful information. The links are now only displayed if the user's role has the ability to edit. BUT, this is only happening on a global scale. ie. moderator can edit/ destroy all users, user cannot edit/ destroy any user. A logged in user should be able to edit/ update themself with the condition statement I used above, right?

Comment: @Andy: Yes, that's right. But be cautious while you are writing down abilities for a user, he can't edit/update his/her role but can change other things.

Comment: @jatin thanks for the tip. shouldn't be a problem in this case as roles are handled through a separate model. I haven't selected your answer yet, even though it's half way there, as I'm still trying to find a solution to displaying the edit link only for the logged in user in index view. Should be relatively straight forward, just need to find the time to think about it and include the full answer here.

Comment: Hope that you achieve what you want to. Happy to help. :)

Comment: @jatin I think my problem is that I haven't defined @user in the user_controller. Sorry for the basic question, but what is the best way to define @user in the index so that it iterates through each record?

Comment: @andy: I am unable to understand when you say that you have not defined @user in the user_controller. Please edit your question, so that I can understand your problem

Comment: @jatin sorry for the confusion. I'm confusing myself here as well! Part of the problem is that I'm trying to tackle multiple issues. Your answer did in fact address the question I asked, so I'm accepting it. I'll ask the next bit as a separate question, and appreciate any further help you can provide. Thanks again! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831168/allow-users-to-edit-destroy-their-own-profiles-only-from-the-index